# Handler Function not called in File Upload Progress Using Form Data And jQuery(1.10.2) Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm creating a message sending interface along with single file upload (few text field and text areas with one file upload button).
I want to show a progress bar while sending message.

I wrote a js function to send message using jquery ajax and it is working fine.

now i m trying to attach progress event. for that i modified my jquery ajax code using google and stack overflow as below:

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('frm_send_msg'));
    var file = document.getElementById('attachment').files[0];
    if (file) {
        form.append('attachment', file);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/send_msg.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //code to hide sending interface
        },
        complete: function() { //     
           alert("complete");
        },
        error: function() {

            alert("ERROR in sending message");
        }
    })
```

And I wrote a function to handle progress event:

```
function progressHandlingFunction(evt) {
    console.log('updating fun called');
    // evt is an ProgressEvent.
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        console.log('updating');
        var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        // Increase the progress bar length.
        $(".progress > div").css({
            width: percentLoaded + '%'
        });

    } else {
        console.log('not updating');
    }
}
```

But i m neither getting any of one console log entry from  progressHandlingFunction function nor my .progress div shows any changes.

need help to solve this please!

**This is what console is showing in chrome**

```
>XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/send_msg.php". 
  send jquery.js:6
  x.extend.ajax jquery.js:6
  send_msg custom_scripts.js:402
  onclick
```

One more thing i want to mention here:

My form is inside twitter bootstrap3.0 modal.?

Comment: What browser are you testing in, just to be sure.

Comment: @Ravi: Are you getting any console errors or warnings? Can you please post your HTML code?

Comment: I modified question see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure will it work or not but modify your ajax code to this and try try removing **success :function(){}** from ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/send_msg.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        complete: function() { //     
//code to hide sending interface
           alert("complete");
        },
        error: function() {

            alert("ERROR in sending message");
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks you mr/ms/mrs ultimate, it worked like charm.. :)